# How to sort a list using my own logic (not alphabetically or numerically)

Tags: c#

I've spent the last 30 mins looking through existing answers for what I think is a common question, but nothing quite hits it for me. Apologies if this is a dupe.

I've got a list of objects.

```
List<Journey> journeys;
```

The object has a 'status' property - this is a string.

```
class Journey
{
    public string Name;
    public string Status; 
}
```

I want to sort based on this string, however not alphabetically. The status depicts the object's position through a journey, either "Enroute", "Finished", or "Error". When sorted ascending I want them to appear in the following order: "Error", "Enroute", "Finished". (In practice there are more statuses than this so renaming them to fall in alphabetical order isn't an option)

Aside from creating a class for 'status' with value and sort order properties, and then sorting based on that, how do I do this? Or is that the best method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the you sorting logic inside of custom function which is provided to [Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) delegate:

```
List<Journey> list = new List<Journey>();

list.Sort(new Comparison<Journey>((Journey source, Journey compare) => 
{ 
    // here is my custom compare logic
    return // -1, 0 or 1
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another thought:

```
class Journey
{
    public enum JourneyStatus
    {
        Enroute,
        Finished,
        Error
    }

    public string Name;
    public JourneyStatus Status;
}
```

Used with OrderBy:

```
var journeys = new List<Journey>();
journeys.Add(new Journey() { Name = "Test1", Status = Journey.JourneyStatus.Enroute });
journeys.Add(new Journey() { Name = "Test2", Status = Journey.JourneyStatus.Error });
journeys.Add(new Journey() { Name = "Test3", Status = Journey.JourneyStatus.Finished });
journeys.Add(new Journey() { Name = "Test4", Status = Journey.JourneyStatus.Enroute });

journeys = journeys.OrderBy(x => x.Status).ToList();

foreach (var j in journeys)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", j.Name, j.Status);
```

Output:

```
Test1 : Enroute
Test4 : Enroute
Test3 : Finished
Test2 : Error
```

Or you might modify the lambda passed to OrderBy to map the value of Status string to an `int`.

In some situations you might want to implement `IComparer<T>`, like Jon said. It can help keeping the sorting logic and the class definition itself in one place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class that implements [`IComparer<Journey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) and implement the `Compare` method accordingly.

You don't mention how you are sorting exactly, but pretty much all methods of the BCL that involve sorting have an overload that accepts an `IComparer` so that you can plug in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

> Aside from creating a class for 'status' with value and sort order properties, and then sorting based on that, how do I do this?

As this is some custom order you need creating such a class is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Derive from [`Comparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx) or [`StringComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) class, implement class with your custom logic, pass instance of this class to sort method.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to assign an order number to each item. So create a database table to hold your items and their order:

```
Column Name, Column Order
Enrout , 0
Finished, 1
Error, 2
```

Then when I populate a drop down I can sort by the Order in my SQL select rather than the name.

Or if you don't want to use a database, you could change Status to include the order and then just parse out the Status name: so Status values might look like this: "0,Enrout","1,Finished","2,Error" then it will naturally sort. Then just use split to separate the order from the name:

```
string[] statusArr = status.split(',');
string order = statusArr[0];
string statusname = statusArr[1];
```

There's a lot of ways to skin this cat.